# Want to get started with Sony Network Camera CGI API and any available SDK

Tags: sony

My company builds and sells an application and decoder to broadcast facilities.  I have a customer with several Sony SNC-ER580 cameras.  This customer is part of a group with many of these cameras.   Does Sony have a CGI and/or camera API manual?  Are there any redistributable COM (ActiveX) controls for use with these cameras?   I would truly appreciate any help someone from Sony could give me in this matter.

Comment: Well - in spite of what Sony says on their web site it's clear they do not  bother to monitor the tag.   I must say trying to get information out of Sony is extremely difficult, they appear to not even answer the inquiry forms from their own web sites.   I suspect they are just too big to care.   Looks like I'll be sticking with Axis Cameras as they have an excellent developers program and have actual people who can answer questions.   Color me very disappointed with Sony.

Comment: P.S. To the Ops of StackOverflow - I'd recommend dropping the Sony tag if they aren't monitoring it.